# StyleSheet makes my TextField text vanish

Tags: actionscript-3, stylesheet, textfield

When I add a StyleSheet as the .styleSheet property to a TextField the text doesn't get drawn.
The problem might be that, when a StyleSheet is needed (I'm using it only to format htmlText links) I can't set a TextFormat. But surely that should just mean the text has NO TextFormat.
Here's the relevant code (I do declare and instantiate the TextField earlier in the code; when I DON'T add the StyleSheet that all works correctly so I'm fairly sure that's not the problem):

```
_linkStyling = new StyleSheet();
_linkStyling.parseCSS('a { color: #99CCFF; }');
_textField.htmlText = p_text; // this is the String parameter passed in to my Text Class
_textField.styleSheet = _linkStyling;
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the same code (with variables declaration and a fixed string) and works fine.
Try to run this simple example, maybe some parameters you are adding for your _textField or your p_text variable are the key of your issue.

```
stage.color = 0x000000;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

var p_text:String = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679148/stylesheet-makes-my-textfield-text-vanish">test</a>';

var _linkStyling:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
_linkStyling.parseCSS('a { color: #99CCFF; }');

var _textField:TextField = new TextField();
_textField.autoSize = 'left';
addChild(_textField);

_textField.htmlText = p_text;
_textField.styleSheet = _linkStyling;
```

Comment: Hmmm... setting the htmlText to a String literal doesn't work for me. Not sure what else it could be, but there must be something weird going on. It seems like it's related to not being able to add a TextFormat because, if I don't apply a TextFormat, even to non-html text, that text does not appear. Gah!

Comment: OK, well, I've put that code into a 'fresh' fla and it doesn't work for me. No errors, but no text. Any pointers? It seems like text doesn't want to appear unless it has a TextFormat applied. Is that the case? That certainly doesn't SEEM right.

Comment: Try with the edited answer, if doesn't work, could you share your FLA file? So, I'll test, because works fine for me.

Comment: OK, got it working in the test .fla. I've added in the code from the project file, line by line and it turns out that, in addition to not being able to add a TextFormat to htmlText, you can't set .embedFonts to true. Thanks; It works now. Now I need to figure out how to use an embedded font in htmlText (so far styling the StyleSheet doesn't work).